# Python pyspark Write DF to .csv and store it in local c drive

Tags: python, pyspark, export-to-csv, apache-zeppelin

I wanted to save a dataframe that pull data using SQLContext and save it into `.csv` file in c drive. I am using Zeppelin to run my code.

The below code runs but I can't see the file in the location specified. The select query in SQLContect is pulling data from HIVE DB.

```
%spark.pyspark

df = sqlContext.sql("SELECT * from TEST")
df.write.format("csv").mode("overwrite").save("\Users\testuser\testfolder\test.csv")

z.show(df)
```

Comment: replace ```\``` with ```\\``` or use forward slashes instead...

Comment: have you fixed it? I have got similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

You're in Windows if I'm getting it correctly. In that case you need to add the required prefix to your path. Your path will be something like `C:\Users\testuser\testfolder\test.csv`

Comment: I have tried this and it still doesn't create a file in C drive.